# Loading in C, integers and characters

Tags: c, integer, character

I am having trouble loading this file.

The first number is how many characters/numbers will be in the subsequent sequences. I do not know/do not know how to figure out if these are numbers or characters.

Here is my code:

The text file is:

```
3
001
100    



 int main(int argc, char** argv)

{
    int  *array =0;
    array = LoadConfig(argv[1]);
    return 0;
}

int* LoadConfig(char * Filename)
{
    FILE* fptr = fopen(Filename, "r");
    int n=0; //number of rows
    int poles=0;
    int i=0; //for loop index
    int scanreturn; //error check
    scanreturn = fscanf(fptr, "%d", &n); // n will be the number of rows
    poles = n*n - n;
    int *array  =malloc(sizeof(int)*(poles));
    for(i=0;i<poles;i++)
    {
        scanreturn = fscanf(fptr, "%d", &array[i]);
        if (scanreturn !=1)
        {
            printf("danger\n");
        }
        printf("%d: %d\n",i, array[i]);
    }
    printf("%d is n  %d is poles\n",n, poles);
    return array;
}


the output is :0: 1
               1: 100
               danger
               2: 0
               danger
               3: 0
               danger
               4: 0
               danger
               5: 0
               3 is n  6 is poles
```

I'm guessing those are characters and not integers then?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1) Insure proper prototyping.  Start with

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int* LoadConfig(char * Filename);
```

2) Only read 1 digit rather than unlimited digits - this is your main issue

```
// scanreturn = fscanf(fptr, "%d", &array[i]);
scanreturn = fscanf(fptr, "%1d", &array[i]);
```

3) Minor: Suggest as it is easier to maintain and more like `calloc()`.

```
// int *array  =malloc(sizeof(int)*(poles));
int *array = malloc(poles * sizeof *array);
```

4) Be sure to free `array` in the calling routine when done with it.

```
free(array);
return 0;
```

5) Check `fscanf()` results

```
scanreturn = fscanf(fptr, "%d", &n);
if (scanreturn != 1) Oops();
```

6) Recommend `fgets()/sscanf() or strtox()` over `fscanf()`

Comment: Thank you so much. I'll make sure to make the edits as you suggested.

Comment: +1. You meant *ensure* :) Sorry for being a pedantic.

Comment: @ajay "Assure vs. Ensure vs. Insure" have similar bit slightly different shades of meaning and I concur "Ensure" would be best in "Ensure proper prototyping."  Apologies not needed - we're all here to help.